# HTML5 webkitSpeechRecognition stops recording after long silence

Tags: html, google-chrome, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, webkitspeechrecognition

Even with "recognition.continuous = true", the recording stops after ~15sec of silence. I need to never stop recording until the user doesn't click the stop button, even after minutes of silence.

I've already set the recording to restart on his onstop(), but the problem is that the user needs to click "Allow" again to enable the microphone (site is http, not https, so the choice isn't remembered by the browser).

The right solution would be to set an option like "REALLY continuous", or to extend the silence-tolerance to several minutes. Is it possibile?

Answer (score 1):

For those that can make their webpages HTTPS: do that (so that it won't keep asking if you want to re-enable the microphone), and then you'll also need to call recognition.start() from within the onend handler.

Note, it this works when continuous = true, but doesn't seem to work when continuous = false.